# How to read XML file in Console app

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, console-application

I will give a set of simple xml lines I found in w3schools XML example.

I want to know how I will be able to access these data from my Console application (I inserted a app.config into by console application project)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <bookstore>
   <book category="cooking">
     <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
     <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
     <year>2005</year>
     <price>30.00</price>
   </book>
   <book category="children">
     <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
     <author>J K. Rowling</author>
     <year>2005</year>
     <price>29.99</price>
   </book>
 </bookstore>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to read a generic XML file, or how to read the app.config file, because those two operations are different.  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually i wanted to access xml data... When i accidently inserted a application configuration file i found out it also has the starting like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` . So i thought i could implement my xml data into application config.. Sorry i might have confused you by the question.. Even i was confused and frustrated by not getting what i wanted....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll assume that you just want to read the XML data. It doesn't really look like configuration so I suppose you're better off putting this in a regular XML file.

You could parse the XML like this:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"XmlFile.xml");

var root = doc.DocumentElement;
if (root == null)
    return;

var books = root.SelectNodes("book");
if(books == null)
    return;

foreach (XmlNode book in books)
{
    var title = book.SelectSingleNode("title");
    var auth = book.SelectSingleNode("author");
    //And so on
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort :) !!! I was confused.. And didnt know how to access xml data..

Comment: country.SelectSingleNode? where is country coming from?

Comment: No idea :) Fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you want to access App.Config you can use `ConfigurationManager` like this :

```
string filetype = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings [ "filetype" ] ;
```

and if you want to work with XML file in c# you can use this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/ReadWriteXMLTutMellli2111282005041517AM/ReadWriteXMLTutMellli21.aspx)
or you can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)